# MySQL connects to a standard java class but not to servlet

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Can you say some possible reasons why MySQL would connect to a regular java class, but not to a servlet? Something is not right when I run in tomcat, but as application everything is fine.

Comment: *"Something is not right"* I agree. Like your question. As in, *what* is not right? *How* is it not right?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is the problem but maybe MySQL driver is not packaged with your war.

If you are using Eclipse, you could try to:
Right button on your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly and
Add your mysql driver to it

If you are using maven be sure to add that dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>your driver version</version>
</dependency>
```

Aside from that, is better to include this driver in your Tomcat libraries folder.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons was jdbc jar file should have also been in tomcat/lib folder, that was my problem.